# Canvas view does not fill relative layout (XAML)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a SkiaSharp canvas view inside a relative layout (Xamarin Forms project). When I use the canvas alone, it fills the entire page. But when I use it inside a relative layout it is not filling the entire space of the relative layout. How to make the canvas to fill the entire relative layout?

[image]

XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyHomeScreen2"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="MyHomeScreen2.MainPage">

    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">

        <views:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnSecondPainting" EnableTouchEvents="True" x:Name="MyCanvas"

              RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                 "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                        Property=X,
                                        Constant=0}"

             RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                 "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                        Property=Y, 
                                        Constant=0}">
        </views:SKCanvasView>

        <BoxView Color="Blue"
            WidthRequest="100" 
            HeightRequest="50"
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
                 "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, 
                                        Property=Width,
                                        ElementName=MyCanvas,
                                        Factor=0.5}"

             RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
                 "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
                                        Property=Y, 
                                        ElementName=MyCanvas,
                                        Constant=25}" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You set canvas X and Y constraints but not width and height

Comment: set it relative to parent width and height with factor 1

Comment: Can I put that as answer if it's resolved? :-) To center box I usually use code behind because you need to know the size of the box and I am not sure how to do it in xaml. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I will post answer for the original question. Can you post another question about centering. I will take a look on it. Just post link to it here

Comment: Is your blue box fixed size or it has to flip in portrait and landscape modes?

Comment: @YuriS It need to flip so that image will be easy to read for the user

Comment: I need details then. If it needs to flip do you have fixed sizes for it or it has to stretch. So please create the question about center and post link here, so I can find it

Comment: @YuriS The size is fixed in fliped view also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas specifies X and Y constraints but not width and height. They should be set relative to parent with factor 1

**XAML**

```
    <views:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnSecondPainting" EnableTouchEvents="True" x:Name="MyCanvas"

          RelativeLayout.XConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, 
                                    Property=X,
                                    Constant=0}"

         RelativeLayout.YConstraint=
             "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                    Property=Y, 
                                    Constant=0}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint = 
                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                           Property=Height,
                                           Factor=1}"

         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint = 
                    "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                           Property=Width,
                                           Factor=1}"                            

                        >
    </views:SKCanvasView>
```